# Is there punctuation which shows possession?

Tags: punctuation, possessives

My question is do you make a sentence a possessive by a punctuation Mark?

Comment: Very good edit @Andrew Leach

Comment: What did you edit?orther wise this is a bully site.I didn't realize you had to be accomplished to join the site.I certainly don't mind being corrected but not to kosher to just edit a question of mine without an explanation,it appears that you are just showing off.So if you can not tell me why edit.:-) Again I'm new and really don't know how this works.But I thought it was a learning tool as well as a teaching site.I hope this site works out I saw alot of great questions&answers before I joined and I hope I can fit in here.

Comment: Questions in Stack Exchange sites need to be just the relevant question. We don't need any history, or thanks [upvotes on answers are good though], just questions and their answers. You've read the Tour: "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I fully understand your question... But I do know that an apostrophe shows possession as in the following:

> Mark's backpack was full of paper.

In the above sentence, Mark possesses the backpack in context. The backpack *is* Mark's.

Comment: +1 for answering this person's question without stuffily suggesting that it be migrated to ELL, or blowing it away because it duplicates sixteen similar queries.  Most ELU responders are civil, and some are actually nice. We're all learning this language.

Comment: -1 for answering a question that duplicates sixteen similar queries (*and* should be on ELL anyway).